# Linear/Integer programming for discrete mathematicians

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, linear-programming, integer-programming

I am primarily a discrete mathematician (designs/finite geometries), and I've been using Gurobi to solve some integer programming problems related to my research.  While I'm comfortable using the software, I feel like I would like to better understand the mathematics involved.

I'm interested in learning about the polytope defined by an integer programming problem.  I'd also like to know about formulating problems; what makes a formulation of a problem "good" or "bad"?

I'm less interested in getting too in-depth about the mechanics of the different algorithms (I'm happy to just know which are better than others in certain situations).

Answer (score 1):

Nemhauser-Wolsey is the encyclopedia. It's a very tough read though, if you don't already know what you're doing. [http://www.amazon.com/Integer-Combinatorial-Optimization-Laurence-Wolsey/dp/0471359432](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471359432)

I really like these notes by Krumke. They're a really good supplement (and even standalone) for your IP studies. http://staff.guilan.ac.ir/staff/users/salahi/fckeditor_repo/file/ip-lecture-new.pdf